# How to only select orders, where orders contain orderitems

Tags: soql, order, orderitem

I have this query but it is returning orders where there a no orderitems present, how can i only select orders that have order items in them?

SELECT EffectiveDate, Description, id, (select order.id from orderitems)
FROM Order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```java
List<Order> orders = [
   SELECT Id, EffectiveDate, Description, (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItems) 
   FROM Order 
   WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem)
];
```

Comment: The explanation is as important as the solution itself.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF, I will apply it to my next answers. :)

Comment: @DerekF Can you please help ? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386763/how-to-find-the-parent-object-of-an-objectstandard-and-custom-object-whose-sha

Comment: @KishanPatel Directly asking members for help like that is considered rude.

Answer (score 3):

A query can do this (only return records with >= 1 child record) through a few different methods:

- Use a *semi join*
- Have a rollup summary field (on `Order`) that counts the number of order items, and use that as a filter in the `WHERE` clause
- Change your query to be based on `OrderItem` instead

Of course, you could always just process the results in Apex too (which may or may not end up being the easiest approach).

A semi-join is a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, and it's generally used to find Ids on related records. It'd look something like this

```
SELECT Id FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId IN :orderIds)
```

Unrestricted queries are a red flag, and set you up for disaster sooner rather than later. The semi-join itself can only select a single field, and it must be an Id or relationship field.

It may seem a bit circular, but such a query does make sense.

- `OrderId IN :orderIds` helps restrict the number of rows you're querying. It may not count towards the queried rows governor limit, but fewer rows still means better performance
- Selecting the `OrderId` in the semi-join, based on `OrderItem` will only return Order Ids that have Order Items
- `WHERE Id IN (SELECT...)` is what actually filters out the Orders without items